# LWIP stack provided by Adacore

Tags: ada, gnat, lwip

I was wondering about 1). porting the LWIP protocol stack to ada or 2). use the protocol stack in C (as it is) and write the interface to it and my ethernet driver in Ada (less work) but then I found out there exists a TCP/IP stack for bare boards:

http://www.adacore.com/labs/tcp-ip-stack/category/embedded-development

Anybody has tried the stack or know how to get the source code?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I have a feeling this is part of Adacore's professional offerings. How big is your budget?

Comment: I thought that source code was also free and downloadable from somewhere. I'd rather keep the LWIP stack in C and write its interface to Ada. Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried the stack, but I'm pretty sure that a support contract with AdaCore is the only practical way to get the source code. - Support contracts with AdaCore start at around 15 kEUR/year.

I would be very happy if you selected option 1 and published the result under an Open Source license, but if your budget is constrained, and you don't have to document the source quality formally, then I think option 2 makes most sense.

Comment: I thought it was free software and that we could get the source code and they (Adacore) provide us the support to bind the stack against the application which is something we have already done it in C. Considering that I spent quite some time porting some drivers (SPI, DMA, GPIOs) from STM32F2xx HAL library to Ada and writing a demo in Ada, I'd go for the option 2 for the quicker solution. If I decide at some point to port the LWIP to Ada, for sure I'll publish it for free. Thanks for your feedback! :)

Comment: I'm not sure you're saying this, but just to clarify anyway...  That something is licensed under the GPL does not obligate the copyright holder to make it available to anyone and everyone.  If you have a GPL-licensed binary product (e.g. application or library) *then* you have the right to its source code. And if you possess GPL-licensed source code, you are free to distribute it as you please within the terms of that license, *but are not obligated to*.

Answer (score 1):

You can get AdaCore ipstack by downloading SPARK GPL.

Look for this directory:
  spark-gpl-2016-x86_64-linux-bin/share/examples/spark/ipstack

See also this announce:
http://www.spark-2014.org/entries/detail/spark-gpl-2015-now-available